# django autocomplete for filtered queryset

Tags: django, filter, django-rest-framework, autocomplete

I am trying to customize django-admin when working with django rest framework. I am adding Article object, which may have Participants (users who contributed to writing the article), and I want to create autocomplete when choosing users, but display only Users who are active and team_members. For now, all Users get displayed despite filtering.

Here is my code:

```
class ParticipantInlineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Participant
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        user_field = self.fields['user']
        if hasattr(user_field, 'queryset'):
            user_field.queryset = user_field.queryset.filter(is_active=True, is_team_member=True)


class ParticipantInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Participant
    form = ParticipantInlineForm
    autocomplete_fields = ['role', 'user']  # here!
```

Here are my User and Participant models:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    """ Расширение стандартной модели пользователя Django """
    patronymic = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Отчество")
    date_joined = models.DateField(null=False, default=timezone.now, verbose_name="Дата регистрации")
    profile_info = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Биография")
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/users/', null=True,
                                        default='images/alt_image.jpg', verbose_name="Аватар")
    is_team_member = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Член команды")
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True,
                                 verbose_name="Полное имя")  # sort of caching for quick search
    article_participated = models.ManyToManyField('Article', through='Participant', related_name='parts',
                                                  verbose_name="Участники в создании")
    favourites = models.ManyToManyField('ContentObject', through='Favourite', related_name='favs',
                                        verbose_name="Избранное")


class Participant(models.Model):
    """ Какую конкретно роль пользователь сыграл при создании """
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             verbose_name="Пользователь")
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Статья")
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name="Фактическая роль")
```

With roles, everything works as expected, probably because I do not need to filter them. If I remove autocompletion, only filtered users are displayed (which is correct). Is it even possible to have autocomplete for a filtered queryset?